# Embedding a simple tikz diagram within a tuple equation

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, equations

I wanted to draw a simple tree using tikz, and embed that tree in an equation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=25mm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx} % <--- For including graphics
\usepackage{listings} % <--- For typesetting verbatim code
\usepackage{tikz}     % <--- For drawing the diagram
\usepackage{array,amsmath}     % <--- For drawing the diagram

\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

\def\mytree{\tikz[inner sep=1pt] {
                  \node (T1) at (0,0) {$T_1$};
                  \node (T2) at (1,0) {$T_2$};
                  \node (INLJ) at (0.5,0.5) {\textsf{IndexJoin}};

                  \node (T3) at (1.5,0.5) {$T_3$};
                  \node (SMJ) at (1,1) {\small{\sf HashJoin}};

                  \node (T4) at (2,1) {$T_4$};
                  \node (HJ) at (1.5,1.5) {\sf HashJoin};

                  \draw (T1)--(INLJ)--(T2);
                  \draw (INLJ)--(SMJ)--(T3);
                  \draw (SMJ)--(HJ)--(T4);
}}

\[ \left( \mytree, 10.111  \right)\]

\end{document}
```

This results in the follow picture:
[image]

You can see there's *a lot of whitespace* beneath both elements of the tuple.  How can I fix this?

Another issue: is there a way to get the "[comma] 10.111" part nicer, say by vertically aligning it with the middle of the tikz picture?

==============

EDIT

Thanks to Phelype's help I'm now able to reduce the whitespace.  However a related question shows up.  I want to `\def` two variants of the tree beforehand and use them afterwards -- but latex gives compilation errors.  If I `\def` one variant, immediately use it, then `\def` and use another variant there's no issues.  Why is that?

OK code (errors out if I use the two trees altogether):

```
\def \tree1 {\tikz[inner sep=1pt, baseline=(T3.north)] {
                  \node (T1) at (0,0) {$T_1$};
                  \node (T2) at (1,0) {$T_2$};
                  \node (INLJ) at (0.5,0.5) {\small{\sffamily IndexJoin}};

                  \node (T3) at (1.5,0.5) {$T_3$};
                  \node (SMJ) at (1,1) {\small{\sffamily HashJoin}};

                  \node (T4) at (2,1) {$T_4$};
                  \node (HJ) at (1.5,1.5) {\small{\sffamily HashJoin}};

                  \draw (T1)--(INLJ)--(T2);
                  \draw (INLJ)--(SMJ)--(T3);
                  \draw (SMJ)--(HJ)--(T4);}}

\[ \left[ \tree1 , \{T1, T2, T3, T4\}; 10.111  \right]\]

\def \tree2 {\tikz[inner sep=1pt, baseline=(T3.south)] {
                  \node (T1) at (0,0) {$T_1$};
                  \node (T2) at (1,0) {$T_2$};
                  \node (INLJ) at (0.5,0.5) {\small{\sffamily IndexJoin}};

                  \node (T3) at (1.5,0.5) {$T_3$};
                  \node (SMJ) at (1,1) {\small{\sffamily HashJoin}};

                  \draw (T1)--(INLJ)--(T2);
                  \draw (INLJ)--(SMJ)--(T3);}}

\[ \left[ \tree2 , \{T1, T2, T3, T4\}; 10.111  \right]\]
```

Comment: Not sure, but I think if you pass the option `baseline=(T3.north)` to the `\tikz` command it will, more or less, solve both problems. _Off-topic_: you shouldn't use `\sf`, but `\sffamily`.

Comment: Thanks!  Mind taking a look at the followup issue?

Comment: You can't use numbers in command names. With the first `\def` you define the command `\tree` (not `\tree1`) and it is required to be followed by the number `1`. Later, you override that definition, and define the command `\tree` (again, not `\tree2`) and its definition _requires_ it to be followed by `2`. Then, when you use `\tree1` TeX says that `Use of \tree doesn't match its definition.`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use `baseline=(current bounding box.center)` to center the [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz) picture. (Not that this matters at all, I would also use a `tikzpicture` environment rather than a `\tikz` command.)

Unless I have missed something the two trees are almost identical except that the second tree has two extra edges. Rather than defining two almost identical commands why not create a `\mytree` and `\mytree*` variant, which is easy to do using `\NewDocumentCommand` from [xparse](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xparse). Doing it this way, here is the output:

[image]

and here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=25mm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx} % <--- For including graphics
\usepackage{listings} % <--- For typesetting verbatim code
\usepackage{tikz}     % <--- For drawing the diagram
\usepackage{array,amsmath}     % <--- For drawing the diagram

\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,shapes.geometric}

\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand\mytree{s}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=1pt, baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
      \node (T1) at (0,0) {$T_1$};
      \node (T2) at (1,0) {$T_2$};
      \node (INLJ) at (0.5,0.5) {\textsf{IndexJoin}};

      \node (T3) at (1.5,0.5) {$T_3$};
      \node (SMJ) at (1,1) {\small{\sf HashJoin}};

      \node (T4) at (2,1) {$T_4$};
      \node (HJ) at (1.5,1.5) {\sf HashJoin};

      \draw (T1)--(INLJ)--(T2);
      \draw (INLJ)--(SMJ)--(T3);
      \IfBooleanT{#1}{\draw (SMJ)--(HJ)--(T4);}
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\[ \left[ \mytree*, \{T1, T2, T3, T4\}; 10.111  \right]\]

\[ \left[ \mytree, \{T1, T2, T3, T4\}; 10.111  \right]\]

\end{document}
```

The `{s}` in `\NewDocumentCommand\mytree{s}{...}` says that the `\mytree` macro has an optional `*`-argument; that is, it can be used as `\mytree` or `\mytree*`. Inside the definition of `\mytree` the line

```
\IfBooleanT{#1}{...}
```

says that if `#1` (exists and) is a `*` then do `{...}`. There are also variants `\IfBooleanTF` and `\IfBooleanF`. See the [xparse](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xparse) documentation for more details.